# Sessions in MVC 5 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing a project about an Chinese food ordering system, and I am wanting show selected items in a view on another page. I am  trying to use sessions, but I keep getting different errors, like "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type" and "object reference is not set to an instance of an object". How can I select the data, and show them in a different view? The project is linked up to a database, the DishID and other instances should be connected through the database.

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using KinaRest.Models;
using KinaRest.View_Models;
using KinaRest.Infrastructure;

namespace KinaRest.Controllers
{
    public class TakeawayController : Controller
    {
        private Basket basket = new Basket();

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult BasketItemsList()
        {
            Basket basket = new Basket();
            return View("_Basket", basket.Items);
        }


        // GET: /Takeaway/

        private ChinaContext db = new ChinaContext();
         [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Dish.ToList());
        }


        [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Index(BasketItem basketItem)
        {
            //Repository repository = new Repository();
            if (Session["Basket"] == null)
            {
                Session["Basket"] = new Basket();
            }
            else
            {
                basket = (Basket)Session["Basket"];
            }
            basket.AddItem(basketItem);

            return View("Test");
        }

    }
}
```

Model 1: Basket

```
namespace KinaRest.Infrastructure
{
    public class Basket
    {
        private List<BasketItem> items = new List<BasketItem>();


        public List<BasketItem> Items { get { return items; } }

        public void AddItem(BasketItem bi) {
            items.Add(bi);
        }
    }
}
```

Model 2: BasketItem

```
namespace KinaRest.Infrastructure
{
    public class BasketItem
    {
        public int DishId {get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
}
```

In this view, we are trying to collect the data, such as the ID, the quantity(number) and price with a form:

```
@model IEnumerable<KinaRest.Models.Dish>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

   <div class="form-group">
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {         

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DishId)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type.Type1)
                </div>
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/" + item.Image)" />





                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <input type="submit" value="Tilføj" class="btn btn-default" />
                }
            }
        </div>
```

In this view, we are trying to access the sessions data:

```
@model List<KinaRest.Infrastructure.BasketItem>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

and yes, I am new to MVC and I am still learning. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Glad you found an answer. But saving your whole resultset into the session does not scale well. How about just saving an id, and then retrieving the required resultset in the proper controller action that will be used to display the actual view?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but this is a small project, just to show something. Doing it big, would probably require what you are suggesting. But thanks for the answer, could become handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Order(int id)
    {

        Dish dish = db.Dish.Single(d=> d.DishId == id); //database call here
        BasketItem basketItem = new BasketItem(){DishId = dish.?, Number = dish.?, Price = dish.Price }; // create a new BasketItem

        Basket basket; //create reference outside if block
        //Repository repository = new Repository();
        if (Session["Basket"] == null)
        {
            basket = new Basket();
            Session["Basket"] = basket;
        }
        else
        {
            basket = (Basket)Session["Basket"];
        }
        basket.AddItem(basketItem);

        return View("Test", basket.Items); //or return View(((Basket)Session["Basket"]).Items); // give the view the data
    }
```

take out the class field basket. As far as i know the controller is instanciated every time when a request is to be processed

View for ordering

```
@model IEnumerable<KinaRest.Models.Dish>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr><th></th><th>Dish</th><th></th></tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr><td><img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/" + item.Image)" /></td><td>@html.displayfor(item => item.Name)</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Order", "TakeAway", new {id = item.DishId})</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer! The problem is now, that it returns zero values as in: 0, 0 and 0.00 as if it can't see the data it should be gathering from the form. Is it getting data from a wrong place?

Comment: usually you just work with id's here so you put a @html.actionlink("Add","Index","TakeAwayController",new {id = item.id}) next to your product data... in the controller you fetch the data from the database with the given id and do whatever you want with it

Comment: Getting a real Basketitem would require a form with all the fields from a basketitem

Comment: How do you add an actionlink to a input, we need the input for the POST session to gather the data, right?

Comment: the users usually prefer dynamic pages working with ajax though so you could use @Ajax.ActionLink and then you could use post methods

Comment: you might want to rethink the whole approach then. keywords: partial views, viewmodels, ajax

Comment: While this is probably preferable in a real life basket case, we only need to return the gathered data, not actually use it for storing or buying purposes. Is there an easy way to get the data and display it in a view? And thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Well the last edits should fix your problems. i renamed the post method and edited the actionlink. in real life you would want to update the view using ajax so that it shows the dishes you ordered. you can look into these keywords in msdn. the description is pretty good.

Comment: We are trying the last edits, but we are not quite understanding the "YourBusinessLogic.GetItem(id)" part. Our database is named ChinaContext, but we can't do the ChinaContext.GetItem thing.

Comment: Well that was a placeholder

Comment: edited again. i dont know what fields you are getting from Dish so i left placeholders

Comment: when i do these kinds of projects i have a business layer which is a class library. hence yourbusinesslogic.GetItem...

Comment: Ah thank you very much, our problem is solved! We'll consider a thoughthrough approach next time, as you suggested! Thanks again.